# $.noop() variable in jQuery works for one cycle, but not two

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script is for a text box to fadeIn onClick then fadeOut onClick.  It works the first time.  But, the second time you do it, the $.noop() variable doesn't work.  [Here's](http://www.paulbedal.com) the link of the site I just started working on.  If you click on the "music","bio", or "links" tabs twice you will see what I'm talking about.  Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#music-box').hide();
    $('#links-top-music').click(function() {
        $('#music-box').fadeIn(1000);
        $.noop();
                $('#links-top-music').click(function() {
                    $('#music-box').fadeOut(750);
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: `$.noop()` doesn't do anything (by definition). Whatever you're trying to do, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: The [noop function on jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop/) does nothing - it's a NO-OPeration function.  It's not meant to be called directly, but passed around for unused callbacks.

Comment: I'm trying to get the box to stay faded in until clicked.  What variable should I use instead?  It works fine for the first fadeIn/fadeOut.  But, after that the pause effect no is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated comment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var buttonStatus = false;
    $('#music-box').hide();
    $('#links-top-music').click(function() {
        if(buttonStatus) {
            $('#music-box').fadeOut(750);
        } else {
            $('#music-box').fadeIn(1000);
        }
        buttonStatus = !buttonStatus;
    });
});
```

This will toggle between visible and invisible.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#music-box').hide();
    $('#links-top-music').click(function(evt) {
        if ($('#music-box:visible').length) {
            $('#music-box').fadeOut(750);
        }
        else {
            $('#music-box').fadeIn(1000);
        }
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/pfT5E/

Comment: I like yours better.  I'll leave mine for posterity.